# MyPy type annotation for a bound method?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I'm writing some tests for a library using `pytest`. I want to try a number of test cases for each function exposed by the library, so I've found it convenient to group the tests for each method in a class. All of the functions I want to test have the same signature and return similar results, so I'd like to use a helper method defined in a superclass to do some assertions on the results. A simplified version would run like so:

```
class MyTestCase:
    function_under_test: Optional[Callable[[str], Any]] = None

    def assert_something(self, input_str: str, expected_result: Any) -> None:
        if self.function_under_test is None:
            raise AssertionError(
                "To use this helper method, you must set the function_under_test"
                "class variable within your test class to the function to be called.")

        result = self.function_under_test.__func__(input_str)
        assert result == expected_result
        # various other assertions on result...


class FunctionATest(MyTestCase):
    function_under_test = mymodule.myfunction

    def test_whatever(self):
        self.assert_something("foo bar baz")
```

In `assert_something`, It's necessary to call `__func__()` on the function since assigning a function to a class attribute makes it a bound method of that class -- otherwise `self` will be passed through as the first argument to the external library function, where it doesn't make any sense.

This code works as intended. However, it yields the MyPy error:

```
"Callable[[str], Any]" has no attribute "__func__"
```

Based on my annotation, it's correct that this isn't a safe operation: an arbitrary Callable may not have a `__func__` attribute. However, I can't find any type annotation that would indicate that the `function_under_test` variable refers to a method and thus will always have `__func__`. Am I overlooking one, or is there another way to tweak my annotations or accesses to get this working with type-checking?

Certainly, there are plenty of other ways I could get around this, some of which might even be cleaner (use an `Any` type, skip type checking, use a private method to return the function under test rather than making it a class variable, make the helper method a function, etc.). I'm more interested in whether there's an annotation or other mypy trick that would get this code working.

Comment: The most typesafe way I can think of is to call `type(self).function_under_test` instead. I don't believe that there is a mypy annotation that does the thing you want. I believe you could build a protocol type that defines `__func__` and assign your function to it, but I see no point.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer I've tested it, a Protocol with `__self__` and `__func__` will not work. Because it seems that mypy has almost no notion of a method. If you reveal_type() on any methods you will see that mypy just recognize them as plain Callables.

Answer (score 0):

*Callable* only makes sure that your object has the `__call__` method.

You problem is your call `self.function_under_test.__func__(input_str)` you should just call your function `self.function_under_test(input_str)`

See below your example without mypy complaints (v0.910)

```py
from typing import Any, Callable, Optional


class MyTestCase:
    function_under_test: Optional[Callable] = None

    def myfunction_wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def assert_something(self, input_str: str, expected_result: Any) -> None:
        if self.function_under_test is None:
            raise AssertionError(
                "To use this helper method, you must set the function_under_test"
                "class variable within your test class to the function to be called.")

        result = self.myfunction_wrap(input_str)
        assert result == expected_result
        # various other assertions on result...


def myfunction(a: str) -> None:
    ...


class FunctionATest(MyTestCase):
    def myfunction_wrap(self, *args, **kwargs):
        myfunction(*args, **kwargs)

    def test_whatever(self):
        self.assert_something("foo bar baz")
```

Edit1: missed the point of the questio, moved function inside a wrapper function

Comment: This does indeed get rid of the mypy errors, but only by making it do something different. Your version doesn't actually work when run: you get `TypeError: myfunction() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. That's because, as I noted in my question, `function_under_test` is a class attribute, and when you don't call `.__func__()`, Python tries to pass `self` as the first argument, which is incorrect since `myfunction` is not a method.

Comment: I missed that point, what about putting your function in a wrapper function? (edited my previous answer)