# Python typing: How to type-hint a variable as a bound method?

Tags: python-3.6, type-hinting

So I have a function (let's call it `fun1`) that accepts a function as a parameter. But inside `fun1`, I *need* to access the parameter's `__self__`, which exists only if the function is a bound method.

The function itself must accept two `str` args and return a `bool`.

In other words, like this:

```py
MyFuncType = Callable[[str, str], bool]

# fun1 is an unbound function
def fun1(func: MyFuncType):
    ...
    o = func.__self__
    ...
    # Some logic on the "o" object, such as logging the object's class,
    # doing some inspection, etc.
    ...
```

If I use `MyFuncType` like the above, PyCharm will complain that `__self__` is not an attribute of `func`.

So, what type hint should I annotate `func` with, so that PyCharm (and possibly mypy) won't protest on that line?

(I'm using **Python 3.6** by the way)

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085648/mypy-type-annotation-for-a-bound-method.

Comment: Huh, the answer there seems to be: You can't 

Comment: Yup sadly, but you might be able to get around it. What prevents you from taking `Callable[[<class>, str, str], bool]`? You would need to pass `Class.method` instead of `self.method`, does your scenario allow that? Then you would declare `o` to be the first argument of that `Callable`.

Comment: The reason is to detect what object `func` was bound to and log that, plus doing some inspection on the object. So, passing a reference to an object to the func definitely won't help. Notice in the example that `fun1` was a standalone function, it has no `self` to pass to `func`.

Comment: I just noticed I made a typo in the sample code that might be the reason of the confusion. Fixed. Sorry about that 

Answer (score 3):

Okay after some experimentation, I settle with this:

```py
class BoundFunc:
    __self__: object

MyFuncType = Callable[[str, str], bool]
MyBoundFuncType = Union[MyFuncType, BoundFunc]

def fun1(func: MyBoundFuncType):
    ...
    o = func.__self__
    ...
```

This does NOT warn me if I pass an unbound function to `fun1`, but at least it suppresses PyCharm's warning when I try to access the `__self__` property.

I figure a proper docstring on `fun1` explicitly saying that `func` MUST be a bound method should be enough for adults...